# Django Using conditional in template based on foreginKey value?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, foreign-keys

I'm wondering if you can use conditions to change what is shown from the template based on a foreignKey. On my project, users will choose a muscle group they want to workout (Chest, Back, Legs, etc.), meaning each workout has a foreginKey to a large muscle group.

I want to make it so if a user chooses a workout that has a foreignKey to Legs, that the template will be unique vs. if the workout was a Chest exercise.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just create different templates, and then render the proper template when it's clicked?

Comment: Well its more than everything is the same, except for a small div section. For a warmup, I don’t want to specify all these sets/reps, but for everything else I want that info.

Comment: You can do it, but there's a good chance it will make your templates bigger, bulkier, and much harder to read. If it really is one small section, yes there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `{% if muscle_part == [ENTER_STRING_TO_VERIFY_WITH] %}` in your HTML and pass the muscle part string in your context while rendering the view. This way all your programs would be in one template but based on your context, they will be displayed accordingly.

Comment: If the foreignKey is within my Workout model, do I need to directly it through as context, or would passing the workout itself be enough?

Comment: you might want to be really specific, or you could just instead of if muscle_part == to some string, you could test if muscle_part_leg exists kinda way, it would help you avoid hardcoding into your template

Comment: Just got it, was actually using single quotes around the string, so it never registered. Double quotes fixed the issue. Thanks for everyone's help!